# Changing block location based on size?

Tags: layout, magento2.3, category-products

I want to have a block (contains a image and some text, nothing overly fancy) appear on the top of the products in a category page when it is on desktop, then on mobile I want it to be on the bottom of the products in the category page. I have figured out that how to put the block on the top with this XML:

```
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cat_arista">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cat_arista</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

But how would I adjust this to show up on the bottom for mobile? I was thinking another layout update call, but I'm not sure if that will lead to it showing up twice. I am using Magento 2, and the pearl theme.

Edit:

I don't know what container would be the bottom the of the product list. I am using this [list](https://gist.github.com/joshfortyfour/11d0f7dbc7be9e85bf4e9c62c668f465) from github, but I'm not sure which one to use.

I also don't think that I can do any css magic because it still will show up in both places?

New edit:
The container for the bottom of the product list is  `content.bottom` . I'll post my css magic as an answer if I figure it out!

Comment: were you able to show it at the bottom? If so, I think you can play it with your custom css

Comment: Hmmm and have something like if it's desktop don't show the bottom one and vice versa?

Comment: yeah exactly. maybe not a Magento standard but I think it will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that then update the question!

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 methods that would work (depending on your DOM structure):

---

**Using two layout blocks**
You can create two blocks each with a unique `name` and then hide/display the relevant one using CSS media queries. To add a unique class to each block you can wrap it in another container, something like this:

```
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
    <container name="some.container.top" as="someContainer" label="Some Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-container some-container--top">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cat_arista_top">
           <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cat_arista</argument>
           </arguments>
       </block>
    </container> 
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <container name="some.container.bottom" as="someContainer" label="Some Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-container some-container--bottom">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cat_arista_bottom">
           <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">cat_arista</argument>
           </arguments>
       </block>
    </container> 
</referenceContainer>
```

Then you can target `some-container--bottom` and `some-container--top` with CSS to hide/show the relevant element.

**Using Javascript**
Another method would be to use Javascript alongside the built in [matchMedia](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd_js.html) (JS media queries) to move the element.

**Using Flexbox/CSS Grid**
The cleanest way would be to use Flexbox or CSS Grid and use the `order` property to position your element, but this depends on your DOM structure.

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating two blocks, cause I have a lot of pages with unique stuff so I would end making like ~100 blocks to do that way. I'll look into the JS option, because I don't know enough about the DOM for this section of magento to use Flexbox (which I'm using inside the blocks) to order it. Thanks!

Comment: The top solution worked for me after working on it for a while